# What does it mean that a random variable is uniformly distributed between two practically speaking?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say I have the explicit density function of $X$, and I'm told that $T$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed between, say $4X$ and $6X$, or $1$ and $X^2+2$, how can I derive the density function, the expected value of $T$, based on this information?

---

This is what I'm sure it means: If $T$ is uniformly distributed between $X$ and $Y$ then $$Exp(T|X)=\frac{1}{2}Exp(X+Y)$$. For the density function I don't know how to derive it at all, but I suspect there might be a trick to first find the cumulative distribution and then differentiate.

Comment: Hello I'm new to this form! Hope I gave enough context to my question, if anything is not clear or you want more details please let me know!

Comment: Add attempts: it gives the community an idea of your overall level of understanding. This will yield better answers to a better question.

Comment: @Snoop Thank you! I added a few changes!

Comment: I've never seen 'the random variable $T$ is uniformly distributed between two random variables $A$ and $B$' before.

Comment: Where have you read that statement that a random variable is distributed between two others ? Is it from a book ? A paper ? It would be nice if you could share the source, because this is not standard terminology

Comment: @StratosFair From an exercise in class.

Comment: I think this means that the conditional distribution of $T$, given that $X$ takes a particular value $x$, is uniform (with parameters determined by $x$). So $T$ models the result of a process where we first sample from $X$ and then sample from a uniform distribution with parameters determined by $X$.

Comment: @Karl I hope I'm not wrong but if $T$ is uniformly distributed between them then we must have $Exp(T|X)=\frac{1}{2}Exp(X+Y)$, this is what I understood.

Comment: Yeah, that statement about the expected value should follow from what I said about the distributions. See [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution).

Comment: @Karl Thanks! But I still don't understand what uniformity implies in this example, and I don't know how to derive the density function.

Comment: I think the way to draw from the distribution would be to draw from $X$, then draw from $Y$ and then draw uniformly from the interval defined by those two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a concrete example, let's say $X\sim U(0,1)$ and "$T\sim U(0,X)$". Using random variables as parameters when specifying the distribution of another random variable isn't really standard (as far as I know), but we can reasonably interpret this as describing a process where we first sample $x$ from a $U(0,1)$ distribution and then "create" a $U(0,x)$ distribution and sample from it.

More formally, this means we have a pair of random variables $X$ and $T$ with the property that the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions) of $T$, given that $X=x$, is the $U(0,x)$ distribution. That is:

$$
f_{T|X}(t|x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x&\text{if $0<t<x$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

so the unconditional distribution of $T$ is

$$
\begin{align}
f_T(t)
&=\int_0^1f_{X,T}(x,t)dx\\
&=\int_0^1f_X(x)f_{T|X}(t|x)dx\\
&=\int_t^1\frac1xdx\\
&=-\log t
\end{align}
$$

for $0<t<1$.

We can check that this is indeed a density function: $-\log t$ is positive on $(0,1)$, and $\int_0^1(-\log t)dt=1$. We also have $\Bbb ET=\int_0^1t(-\log t)dt=\frac14=\frac12(\Bbb E0+\Bbb EX)$, which matches your expectation. (No pun intended!)

---

Edit: As pointed out in a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602107), instead of defining $T$ by its conditional distribution, we can think of $T$ as the result of translating and scaling a new independent $U(0,1)$ random variable onto the desired interval. That is, $T\sim U(X,Y)$ means $T=X+(Y-X)Z$, where $Z\sim U(0,1)$ is independent from $X$ and $Y$. From this it follows immediately that $\Bbb ET=\frac12(\Bbb EX+\Bbb EY)$, but I think determining other properties of the distribution will involve the same calculus as above.